# How to write a stored procedure to insert values in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

[image: Database Schema]

How do I write a stored procedure to add a person record with **multiple addresses?**

It is easy if the person has only one address but I'm not sure how to write a stored procedure to add a person with multiple addresses.
Here is the stored procedure to add a person with one address:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE `log`.`spAddPerson` (
 IN personID INT,
 IN personName VARCHAR(100),
 IN addressLine1 VARCHAR(45),
 IN addressLine2 VARCHAR(45),
 IN myCity VARCHAR(45),
 IN myState VARCHAR(45),
 IN myCountry VARCHAR(45)
```

)

```
 BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
 BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
 END;

 START TRANSACTION;

 INSERT INTO person VALUES(personID,personName);
 -- addressid is automatically generated
 INSERT INTO address(Line1, Line2,City,State,Country) VALUES
 (addressLine1, addressLine2, myCity,myState, myCountry);

 INSERT INTO personAddress(personID, last_insert_id());

 COMMIT;

 END
```

The above code works fine. However, I do not know how to handle a person with multiple addresses without writing a separate stored procedure. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why not call the procedure separately for each address?

Comment: If I do what you say: Rowland, I would have to check to ensure that the person I am adding is not already in the database for each address the person has; furthermore if one of the inserts fail, I won't be able to rollback the entire procedure.

Comment: I think you have to split the logic of your program: First: Check if the person exists; if it doesn't exist, insert it. Second: Add the address (or addresses).

Comment: Barranka: I have already thought about that; however, I have three concerns: 1. How will I rollback the transaction 2. What impact will it have on performance later on 3. Is splitting the logic the best practise in this situation

Comment: Unrelated: is there really an many-to-many relationship between `person` and `address`, or shouldn't there just be a foreign key in `address` to `person` (one-to-many relationship).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a variable number of variables to a procedure, nor a non-scalar type.

A possible trick would be building a temporary table with the addresses before calling this procedure. Either the temporary table is pre-determined, or pass its name as a `VARCHAR` parameter(and use it to build dynamic SQL statements). Eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddPerson (tmp_table VARCHAR(10), ...)
BEGIN
    ...
    PREPARE s AS CONCAT(
        'INSERT INTO address (line1, ...) VALUES SELECT * FROM ', tmp_table
    );
    EXECUTE s;
    ...
END


-- use it like this
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_addresses (line1 VARCHAR(255), ...);
INSERT INTO tmp_addresses VALUES ('1 Cherry Lane'), ... ;
CALL spAddPerson ('tmp_addresses', ...);
```

However, I would rather split the action in two parts. Do you really want to prevent the creation of the `person` altogether if its address creation fails? And even then, wouldn't you want to advise your user why the transaction failed (user creation or address creation)?

I would rather treat these two exceptions separately at the application level:

```
    issue a "START TRANSATION"
    try to insert a person (call stored proc 1)
    if it failed, rollback and notify user
    for each address
        try to insert an address (call stored proc 2)
        if it failed, rollback and notify user
    issue a "COMMIT"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>     DECLARE @LAST_INSERT_ID INT
>     DECLARE @EXECUTION_OK char(1)
>     SET @EXECUTION_OK = 1
>     
>     insert into base_table(imgPath,store,apparelType) values (imgPath,store,apparelType)
>     
>         SELECT @LAST_INSERT_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
>         
>         insert into data_table(cvID,color) values (@LAST_INSERT_ID, color)
>         GO
>         
>         If exists( Select cvID from data_table where cvID= @LAST_INSERT_ID)
>         Begin
>         @EXECUTION_OK = 0
>         End
```